# Unable to import SMOTE due to error <<ImportError: cannot import name 'lobpcg' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' >>

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, imblearn

Unable to import SMOTE due to error 
**ImportError: cannot import name 'lobpcg' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (E:\Installations\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py)**

Above error is displayed when I am trying to import below packages

```
from imblearn.combine          import SMOTETomek

from imblearn                  import under_sampling, over_sampling

from imblearn.over_sampling    import SMOTE

I have conda installed sklearn, imbllearn. Can some one help me to resolve this error
```

Answer (score 2):

This is error is raised within scikit-learn.

Be sure to install both library using:

```
conda install scikit-learn -c conda-forge 
conda install imbalanced-learn -c conda-forge
```

Be aware that I am using the `conda-forge` channel to install scikit-learn to get the version `0.22` because the latest version is not available on the `conda` default channel for the moment.